# Tamil dotted circle in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, air, tamil

I'm making an AIR application that displays a quiz created in a back-office.
Everything is fine with any language: the questions' `TextFields`, even when wrapping, do not "hyphenate".

When displaying a Tamil text, the questions show a little dotted circle at automatic carriage returns (I can't read Tamil and I can't find anyone around me who can). I believe this is the equivalent to hyphens in occidental alphabets.

[image: Tamil dotted circles]

I have two questions:

Is this a problem that these circles appear in a text (even if they are not present in the back-office)? Is it an error, is it just ugly, is it totally normal and good-pratice?

Does someone know how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears when the font is not embedded and when using the `TextField` class.
If the font is embedded the problem disappears but other misinterpretations of Tamil characters occur.

Conclusion: `TextField` does not support Tamil language (am I the first one to notice that???).
The only solution is to switch to `TLFTextField` (available as a swc with Flash). Don't forget to embed the font as CFF when using TLF.